# Как запустить проект правильно?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Есть вот такой проект https://github.com/WentianZhang-ML/FRT-PAD, хочу запустить его локально.
В самом конце сказано, что можно запустить как

```
python train_main.py \
--train_data [om/ci]
--test_data [ci/om]
--downstream [FE/FR/FA]
--graph_type [direct/dense]
```

В `juputer` пробую запустить этот файл, но получаю `SystemExit: 2`

Comment: Запускайте без jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запускать нативно, т.е. в терминале с этим файлом выполните команду для запуска. Скорее всего на jupyter происходят какие-то проблемы с парсингом аргументов. Судя по коду в репозитории он подразумевает запуск в обычном python окружении.